# How to have only a vertical scroll bar on a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table which is in a div. The length of the table can vary and I use the div to enforce a height.

```
<div id='CamListDiv'>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th><input type='checkbox' id='selectAll'/></th>
        <th>Local Camera List</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>//camera 1 data //</td></tr>
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>//camera x data //</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

CSS
#CamListDiv {
    height: 340px;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

My problem is when the vertical scrollbar is needed, the space it occupies causes a horizontal scrollbar to appear. 
I don't need the horizontal scrollbar and I tried to use the `overflow-y: hidden;` css property to hide it but this causes both scrollbars to be hidden.

Does anyone know why `overflow-y:hidden;` isn't working as expected or how to stop the horizontal scrollbar from being visible?

Comment: I asked this on a Friday morning, which you can probably guess. I really should have known x is across and y is up! Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are hiding the vertical scrollbar, and not the horizontal one.

Change `overflow-y: hidden;` to `overflow-x: hidden;`

---

Heres a [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrrKX/)

I've added content surpassing the height, and a `div` with a width greater than 340px inside `#CamListDiv`. The content is only scrollable vertically.

Answer (score 1):

By the way the overflow-y property does not work properly in IE8 and earlier.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

Try setting a style="width:100%;" to the table inside the div, that should hide the horizontal bar because it won't be larger than it's container.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Overflow-y which comes in css2, see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow)

Comment: `overflow` is a CSS 2 property.